# How to convert a String to a Date using SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

I have this code snippet:

```
DateFormat formatter1;
formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/DD/yyyy");
System.out.println((Date)formatter1.parse("08/16/2011"));
```

When I run this, I get this as the output:

```
Sun Jan 16 00:10:00 IST 2011
```

I expected:

```
Tue Aug 16 "Whatever Time" IST 2011
```

I mean to say I am not getting the month as expected. What is the mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java SimpleDateFormat always returning January for Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560279/java-simpledateformat-always-returning-january-for-month)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [modern correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49706789/642706) by Ole V.V.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

- `MM` is "month" (not `mm`)
- `dd` is "day" (not `DD`)

It's all in the [javadoc for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

FYI, the reason your format is still a valid date format is that:

- `mm` is "minutes"
- `DD` is "day in year"

Also, you don't need the cast to `Date`... it already *is* a `Date` (or it explodes):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("08/16/2011"));
}
```

Output:

```
Tue Aug 16 00:00:00 EST 2011
```

Voila!

Comment: No luck.. :( Its still Jan.. No matter what value i give to MM it always displays me Jan. Date and year working fine..

Comment: @Bohemian: If I use the same format (MM/dd/yyyy) with a wrong date (i.e. 02/40/2013), the parsing doesn't fail. I obtain 12 March 2013. Why? Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: @Cricket the value is successfully parsed as the 40th day in February, simply rolling over to a day in March to accommodate the out of bounds value. To prevent this, call [`setLenient(false);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) on the format object before parsing (leniency is true by default).

Answer (score 46):

m - min M - Months

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
G       Era designator          Text                AD
y       Year                    Year                1996; 96
M       Month in year           Month               July; Jul; 07
w       Week in year            Number              27
W       Week in month           Number              2
D       Day in year             Number              189
d       Day in month            Number              10
F       Day of week in month    Number              2
E       Day in week             Text                Tuesday; Tue
a       Am/pm marker            Text                PM
H       Hour in day (0-23)      Number              0
k       Hour in day (1-24)      Number              24
K       Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number              0
h       Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number              12
m       Minute in hour          Number              30
s       Second in minute        Number              55
S       Millisecond             Number              978
z       Time zone               General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z       Time zone               RFC 822 time zone   -0800
```

Comment: Thanks for the table, really helpful having it on this page

Answer (score 12):

Use the below function

```
/**
     * Format a time from a given format to given target format
     * 
     * @param inputFormat
     * @param inputTimeStamp
     * @param outputFormat
     * @return
     * @throws ParseException
     */
    private static String TimeStampConverter(final String inputFormat,
            String inputTimeStamp, final String outputFormat)
            throws ParseException {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat).format(new SimpleDateFormat(
                inputFormat).parse(inputTimeStamp));
    }
```

Sample Usage is as Following:

```
    try {
        String inputTimeStamp = "08/16/2011";

        final String inputFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        final String outputFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";

        System.out.println(TimeStampConverter(inputFormat, inputTimeStamp,
                outputFormat));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String newstr = "08/16/2011";
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(format1.parse(newstr));
System.out.println(format.format(c.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 4):

Very Simple Example is.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Date date = new Date();
                Date date1 = new Date();
            try {
                System.out.println("Date1:   "+date1);
                System.out.println("date" + date);

                date = simpleDateFormat.parse("01-01-2013");
                date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("06-15-2013");

                System.out.println("Date1 is:"+date1);
                System.out.println("date" + date);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: "06-15-2013" should be replaced with "15-06-2013"

Answer (score 4):

This piece of code helps to convert back and forth

```
    System.out.println("Date: "+ String.valueOf(new Date()));
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String stringdate = dt.format(new Date());
    System.out.println("String.valueOf(date): "+stringdate);

    try {
    Date date = dt.parse(stringdate);
    System.out.println("parse date: "+ String.valueOf(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can solve the problem much simple  like 
First convert the the given string to the date object 
 eg:

```
java.util.Date date1 = new Date("11/19/2015"); 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mma");
String format = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(format);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("08/16/2011", dateFormatter));
```

Output:

> 2011-08-16

I am contributing the modern answer. [The answer by Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9872444/5772882) is correct and was a good answer when it was written 6 years ago. Now the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class is long outdated and we have so much better in `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. I warmly recommend you use this instead of the old date-time classes.

### What went wrong in your code?

When I parse `08/16/2011` using your snippet, I get `Sun Jan 16 00:08:00 CET 2011`. Since lowercase `mm` is for minutes, I get `00:08:00` (8 minutes past midnight), and since uppercase `DD` is for day of year, I get 16 January.

In `java.time` too format pattern strings are case sensitive, and we needed to use uppercase `MM` for month and lowercase dd for day of month.

### Question: Can I use java.time with my Java version?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on Java **6** and later and on both older and newer Android devices.

- In Java 8 and later and on new Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
String localFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), "EEEE MMMM d");
return new SimpleDateFormat(localFormat, Locale.getDefault()).format(localMidnight);
```

will return a format based on device's language.
Note that getBestDateTimePattern() returns "the best possible localized form of the given skeleton for the given locale"

Answer (score 1):

You have used some **type errors**. If you want to set **08/16/2011** to following pattern. It is wrong because,

**mm** stands for **minutes**, use **MM** as it is for **Months**

**DD** is **wrong**, it should be **dd** which represents **Days**

Try this to achieve the output you want to get (  `Tue Aug 16 "Whatever Time" IST 2011` ),

```
    String date = "08/16/2011"; //input date as String

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); // date pattern

    Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date); // returns date object 

    System.out.println(myDate); //outputs: Tue Aug 16 00:00:00 IST 2011
```