# How to compare a date - String in the custom format "dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss" with another one?

Tags: java, date, format

I have to  check 2 date `String`s in the custom format `"dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss"` against each other.
How can I get the older one?

For example :

```
String date1 = "05.02.2013, 13:38:14";
String date2 = "05.02.2013, 09:38:14";
```

Is there a way to get `date2` with comparing?

Comment: what have you tried? Use simpleFormatDate and parse it to date and then compare them with compareTo

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872419/converting-string-to-date-using-simpledateformat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the date format, use it with [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and then [compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) the created [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects.

**[See demo here.](http://ideone.com/OVVwrA)** Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  Exception {
    String date1 = "05.02.2013, 13:38:14";
    String date2 = "05.02.2013, 09:38:14";
    System.out.println(getOlder(date1, date2)); // 05.02.2013, 13:38:14
    System.out.println(getOlder(date2, date1)); // 05.02.2013, 13:38:14
}

public static String getOlder(String one, String two) throws ParseException {
    Date dateOne = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss").parse(one);
    Date dateTwo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss").parse(two);
    if (dateOne.compareTo(dateTwo) > -1) {
        return one; // or return dateOne;
    }
    return two; // or return dateTwo;
}
```

Of course, the method above returns the oldest date string entered. You can changed it (see the comments) to return the `Date` object instead.

Answer (score 5):

I'll just give you a brief explanation of how you should proceed. 
You need to first parse those date strings into `Date` object. Use [`DateFormat#parse(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) for that.
After you get the `Date` object out of those strings, you can compare those objects using [`Date#compareTo(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Calulations with date and time are always tricky and I strongly recommend to use appropiate classes for this, you might want to check [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Their classes provide methods such as [daysBetween](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) that give you the result you want.

Of course you have to parse your String to give you an Object representing this date and time first.