# In Ruby, compare two strings as dates and get the older one

Tags: ruby, date, compare

Much like this OP asked in Java, I'd like to know how to do in Ruby:

[How to compare a date - String in the custom format “dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss” with another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643743/how-to-compare-a-date-string-in-the-custom-format-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-with)

I have these two strings, which convey dates and time and I would like to find the older one of the two:

20141024_133641
20141024_142440

The format is %Y%m%d_%H%M%S ; which makes the former the older one in this case.

Comment: Sort them, first will be older, last -- newer )

Comment: Your format is simliar to that of [ISO 8601](http://devblog.avdi.org/2009/10/25/iso8601-dates-in-ruby/). If you can alter the format, consider using ISO 8601. One reason is that Ruby provides [Date#iso8601](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) to convert the strings to `Date` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DateTime.parse`

```
 d1 = DateTime.parse("20141024_142440","%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
 d2 = DateTime.parse("20141024_133641","%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
```

and compare them as usual

```
 if d1 > d2 ...
```

or like @kroky said

```
[d1,d2].min.to_s #=> "2014-10-24T13:36:41+00:00"
[d1,d2].max.to_s #=> "2014-10-24T14:24:40+00:00"
```

Answer (score 10):

Plain lexicographical string comparison will do the job here as your date strings are ordered from most significant to least significant (years to seconds) in strict order. If `d1` is your first date and `d2` is your second date string, then simple ruby will get the older one:

`[d1,d2].min`