# How to cut and replace String

Tags: java

I have a following string which I have to split and replace with "/" on some condition**

```
String date = "20131105";
```

I want to change these string to "2013/11/05"

**Edit:**

***I mean variable date must be String not Date data type***

Comment: do you want to change dates or want to do similar operation on any string? if dates then look at SimpleDateFormat http://stackoverflow.com/a/9872444/1544069

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: its better to use date format rather then using substring operation in this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the substring method.

```
date = date.substring(0, 4) + "/" + date.substring(4, 6) + "/" + date.substring(6, 8);
```

Answer (score 12):

Do like this

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("20131105");
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

**Output**

```
2013/11/05
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 String date = "20131105";
String date1=date.substring(0, 4);
String date2=date.substring(4,6);
String date3=date.substring(6,8);
System.out.println(date1+"/"+date2+"/"+date3);
```

**output** 2013/11/05

Answer (score 2):

See you have many logics .. you can use any one..

for example answer from prabhakaran which is

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("20131105");
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

here you can do one change like this

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(StringVaribale);
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

here you are converting to date and then converting back to string

Another one is you can take a substring and add "/" into your string
in this logic you should take StringBuffer insteed of string. because this is having some extra feature.