# Date format throwing error

Tags: java, date

Below code is throwing an exception while parsing the date.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
String timestamp = "20131113-210429";
String suffix;
try {
     suffix = df.format(timestamp);
}
```

Where can i get the list of permissible date formats?

Comment: Don't you want to do parse()?

Comment: *where can I get the list of permissible date formats*: in the javadoc of the class you're using: SimpleDateFormat, or course: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

Your hour should be `HH` for 24 hours format, current it is `hh` which is for `12` hours format.

So your format should be: `"yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"`

Comment: am getting the same error when changed to the "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"

Comment: @user170008, you need to parse the string to Date using this format, you can't format a string using `SimpleDateFormat`. See this question for how to do parsing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872419/converting-string-to-date-using-simpledateformat

Answer (score 2):

[Java API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) are always your friend.