# How to convert date(String) into Date format(yyyy-MM-dd) in Android?

Tags: android, date

Am getting current date using `date picker`. Using **StringBuilder** it displayed like this **(10-08-2014)** now I can able to get that in string using `String selecteddate=datepick.getText().toString();`

`selecteddate=10-08-2014` but i need to store in database like this **(2014-08-10).** How to convert a string value(10-08-2014) inti string value(2014-08-10) ? Help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872419/converting-string-to-date-using-simpledateformat   Best Soluation

Comment: [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) don't have `getText()` method. What is `datepick`?

Comment: datepick is the `TextView` it is used for displaying date that picked form DatePicker

Comment: you can use my snippet before setting text to TextView. I it is the answer for your question

Answer (score 1):

Use *SimpleDateFormat* Class

```
Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // Current time
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // Set your date format
String currentData = sdf.format(d); // Get Date String according to date format
```

Comment: Hi, I get date from datepicker and set it to `textview` now i need to get that textview in string n then convert to this format(yyyy-MM-dd)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Date cDate = new Date();
 String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cDate);
```

You may use this also

and if you want to set selecteddate=10-08-2014 in yyyy-mm-dd format you can use

```
String s[] = selecteddate.split("-");
String newdate = s[2]+"-"+s[1]+"-"+s[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this Code, It suits to your requirement.

```
      String date="10-08-2014";
        DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date d;
        try {
            d = df.parse(date);
            df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String myDate = df.format(d);
           Log.i(TAG,myDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {}
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer for you. No need to write anything new here.

Comment: Hi, yeah its working fine d prints in `logcat` exactly what i expected but here i cont store d Date directly so i used string date=d.tostring(); but it showing date and time in american format.

Comment: I edited my answer. now you can save **myDate** in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Simple date format:

```
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    // Display a date in day, month, year format
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
    String today = formatter.format(date);
    System.out.println("Today : " + today);
```

Link for the code above: [Simple Date Format](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Formatadateintoddmmyyyy.htm)

Code snippet: DatePicker example find more in the link below:

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    textView.setText(new StringBuilder()
    .append(year) .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
    .append(" "));
```

Here you can find a great example: [Mkyong android-date-picker-example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/)