# Format String with date to other format

Tags: android

How can I format string with date: `2015-02-17T12:12:17+01:00` to  `17.02.2015, 12:12`? This is possible? I read about SimpleDateFormat, but I don't know How can I write format for this example.

Comment: I don't know why Blackbelt marked my question as duplicate NetworkOnMainThread

Comment: I think @Blackbelt fumbled a copy/paste here.

Comment: my mistake, I pressed on the wrong button. It is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872419/converting-string-to-date-using-simpledateformat)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2375539/2106820

Comment: the pattern you have to use to parse the date is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`. the `parse` will return you a Date object that you can use to `format` the date the way you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited**This is an example of SimpleDateFormat class use..hope this get you to the answer

```
String date_s = " 2011-01-18 00:00:00.0"; 
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
Date date = dt.parse(date_s);  
 SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ ");
 System.out.println(dt1.format(date));
```

Comment: your answer is wrong. OP's date is a different format

Comment: @edi233, it the answer is wrong, why did you accepted it?