# Creating date in java with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date

**Update**:
Really?!!! Duplicate??? My format is correct `(yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss)` but return time is incorrect. How this is similar to another question????

I'm trying to create java `Date` but it's always return wrong value. This is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:SS");
Date GreDate = dateFormat.parse("2014/03/22 00:00:00");
```

And `GreDate` return `Sun Dec 22 00:00:00 GMT+03:30 2013` as value.
Please don't suggest to use external library for date type.

*Update:*

I changed my pattern to this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Now `GreDate` returns `Sat Mar 22 01:00:00 GMT+04:30 2014`. Year is correct but time still not `00:00:00`.

Comment: *"M | Month in year (context sensitive) | Month | July; Jul; 07"*; *"m | Minute in hour Number | 30"* ; *"S | Millisecond | Number | 978"*.  Don't forget to have a read through [the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Possibly the same question [Converting String to date using SimpleDateFormat.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872419/converting-string-to-date-using-simpledateformat)

Comment: it should be timezone issue,`dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("${inputyourtimezone}"));` you can set timezone before date parse.

Comment: I also think your question has the answer there. If you don't agree, edit your question to make clear the difference, and explain it in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

- MM are the months, mm are the minutes.
- SS are the milliseconds, ss are the seconds.

So you need to change your dateFormat to

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Basically there are two errors in your pattern, both in the time part (seconds and minutes).

Here is the link to the complete documentation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: That's solve year problem and return 'Sat Mar 22 01:00:00 GMT+04:30 2014' But I want time be 00:00:00 Not 01:00:00

Comment: @HosseinR What does `System.out.println(dateFormat.format(GreDate));`?  I suspect that your timezone might be interfering with your results

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's return "2014/03/22 01:00:00"

Comment: @HosseinR Hmm, works fine for :P.  What's your TimeZone

Comment: @MadProgrammer My timezone is +4:30 (Tehran)