# Compare two strings that contain a date to check if one is before or after the other

Tags: java, arrays, string, calendar, client-server

I've written some code for a client-server application which allows the server to set up 2 deadlines for 2 different items. These items have a deadline at which the server should display when the time reaches it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
String[] deadlines = new String[2];

Calendar deadline = Calendar.getInstance();

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{

    System.out.print("Enter finishing time for item " + (i+1) + " in 24-hr format "); // Item 1
    System.out.print("(e.g. 17:52) :  ");
    String timeString = input.nextLine(); // get input

    String hourString = timeString.substring(0,2);
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(hourString);

    String minString = timeString.substring(3,5);
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(minString);                   

    deadline.set(year,month,date,hour,minute,0);

    deadlines[i] = getDateTime(deadline);

    System.out.print("\nDeadline set for item " + (i+1) + "\n");
    System.out.println(getDateTime(deadline)+ "\n\n");
}

System.out.println("\nServer running...\n");


Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.print(deadlines[0]); // HERE
System.out.print(deadlines[1]); // AND HERE
// getDateTime(now) outputs the same as deadlines[0] + deadlines[1].


while(now.before(deadlines[0]) || now.before(deadlines[1])) // THIS LINE
{
    //System.out.println(getDateTime(now));

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException intEx)
    {

    }

    now = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (now.after(deadlines[0]))
        System.out.println("\n\nDeadline reached" + deadlines[0] + "\n");
    if (now.after(deadlines[1]))
        System.out.println("\n\nDeadline reached" + deadlines[1] + "\n");
}

public static String getDateTime(Calendar dateTime)
{
    //Extract hours and minutes, each with 2 digits
    //(i.e., with leading zeroes if needed)...

    String hour2Digits = String.format("%02d", dateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    String min2Digits = String.format("%02d", dateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

    return(dateTime.get(Calendar.DATE) 
            + "/" + (dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) 
            + "/" + dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) 
            + "  "+ hour2Digits + ":" + min2Digits);
}
```

I need to check whether `now` is before the values of `deadlines[0]` and `deadlines[1]`. How can I do this? There must be a better way than converting it into a string etc?

Comment: Having two date objects would be easier to compare than Strings. Use SimpleDateFormat to convert String to a Date object.

Comment: @Nambari Could you please show me how to do this?

Comment: There are lot of examples on StackOverflow, simple search could help you, here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872419/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-date-using-simpledateformat

Comment: So, would I have to make `deadline` a `SimpleDateFormat` Date object? or do you mean make both that and the `now` Calendar instance?

Comment: Make both Calendar instance and try to compare.

Comment: Is there any other ways of doing this or is this the most efficient way of doing this? I'm only really comparing the times. The dates are exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `LocalTime#parse`, it takes the exact format you're wanting the user to enter.

```
String input = "17:52";
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(input); // 17:52
```

Then pass it to a `LocalDateTime#of` with a `LocalDate`

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(year, month, day), lt);
```

If you need to compare them, use `compare()`, `isAfter()` or `isBefore()`

```
while (LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(ldt)){
    // doStuff
}
```

---

### EDIT

If you want to access the object outside of the loop, keep going with the same array logic if you want.

```
LocalDateTime[] dateTimes = new LocalDateTime[2];

for (//){
    datesTimes[i] // for example
}
```

Comment: Problem is, I declared the time values inside the for loop and the check occurs outside of the for loop so I can't set the value of `LocalTime lt`. Any way of solving this?

Comment: @Olehi Just declare an array, like you did before. Or use an `ArrayList`

Comment: Is this the only way of doing it?

Comment: @Olehi This is one way of doing it.

Comment: I don't fully understand where to place each of the lines. Could you please show me with my code from the main question?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dateTime = f.parseDateTime("2012-01-10 23:13:26");

DateTime now = new Date();

if(now.compareTo(dateTime)<=0){
   // dateTime is in the past
}
```