# How to insert a date from form to a column whose type is Datetime in database

Tags: java

I got the date which is a string from a form. The date looks like xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx

How can I save this date string to a column whose type is datetime in the database.

I use PreparedStatement psta = new PreparedStatement(sql) to set the values for the sql.

So for the Datetime type column, when i pre-set the value. I should use 
psta.setDate() or use psta.setString()?

Comment: you have to use setDate

Comment: use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert String to Date, then use `setDate()`

Comment: Use `setTimestamp()`, not `setDate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ignore all the comments and other answers that says to use `setDate()`. Instead, you have to use `setTimestamp()`, because your date string has time-of-day (hour, minute, second).

1. First, you have to parse the text using [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
2. Then convert from [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).
3. Finally call [`setTimestamp()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-).

All in all, like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date date = fmt.parse(dateString);
psta.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Comment: I use setTimestamp. But an error, java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, is thrown. I checked the number of my parameters and the name of parameters with the columns in the table. It is the same

Comment: @Will You'd have to show more of your code for help with that, but that's a different question. This is the answer to this question. Create another question for problem matching up `setXxx()` calls with `?` markers in your SQL statement.

Comment: @ Andreas Thank you so much, and i fixed the error. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use SimpleDateFormat to convert your String to Date.

   ref: [How to convert a String to a Date using SimpleDateFormat?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9872419/2815219)
2. Use `psta.setDate()` to set date for your sql query.

   ref : [Using setDate in PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18615191/2815219)