# CSV to JSON and add title

Tags: json, csv, type-conversion

I have a csv document:

```
{
    "epsilon_id": 194029423,
    "weather": "cloudy",
    "temperature": 27
},
{
    "epsilon_id": 932856192,
    "weather": "sunny",
    "temperature": 31
}
```

I was wondering if there was a tool to make it into valid json where the field  `epsilon_id`  is the title for the data.

ex:

```
{
    194029423: {
        "weather": "cloudy",
        "temperature": 27
    },
    932856192: {
        "weather": "sunny",
        "temperature": 31
    }
}
```

I would prefer it to be a program (in whatever language) that I can run because I have 1,000 entries in my test sample and I will have tens of thousands in my final copy.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: why is that `csv` ? looks like json to json ?

Comment: @corn3lius I wasn't sure how to format the csv, so I just threw it into the first csv to json converter I found online to make it easier to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at JSON transformation, and ofcourse can be achieved with a custom programming. I can explain you how you can achieve this in Java, but functionally its gonna be the same for any programming of your choice.
Your input json will look like this:

```
[{
    "epsilon_id": 194029423,
    "weather": "cloudy",
    "temperature": 27
},
{
    "epsilon_id": 932856192,
    "weather": "sunny",
    "temperature": 31
}]
```

When you parse in java using popular Jackson library, you will get list of object for below class:

```
class Input
{
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    String epsilon_id,
    String weather,
    int temperature
}
```

Then you create a map object `Map<Integer, Input>`, populate data like below:

```
Map<Integer, Input> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Input obj : listOfInputs){
 map.put(obj.epsilon_id, obj)
};
```

Serialize your result map using Jackson again to get your desired output format:

```
{
    194029423: {
        "weather": "cloudy",
        "temperature": 27
    },
    932856192: {
        "weather": "sunny",
        "temperature": 31
    }
}
```

If you are not very familiar with Java & Jackson JSON parsing, I found this [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial) with code sample, which will give you headstart.

Comment: Okay thanks! Would it also be possible for me to reformat dates after pulling them out of a field?

Comment: I don't see date field in your json, but yes once your string date is read in Java object, you can change its format using `SimpleDateFormat` class. [Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872419/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-date-using-simpledateformat) & [Reference2](http://www.java67.com/2013/01/how-to-format-date-in-java-simpledateformat-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv, json, os
# rename this file or pass it in as process.argv[2] 
#  then pipe output into another file. or 
with open("./foo.csv") as f: 
  output = {} 
  for line in csv.DictReader(f):
    key = line.pop("epsilon_id")
    if output.has_key(key):
      print("Duplicate Id -> {} ".format(key))
    output[key] = line

#  then pipe this output into another file.
print(json.dumps(output, indent=2))
# or write a file
with open("/tmp/foo.json",'w') as f:
    json.dump(output, f)
```

Python makes it pretty easy : this will detect all types from a csv file.

demo : https://repl.it/@markboyle/UsableIcyFeed