# Why is SimpleDateFormat parsing Date with wrong Month and Day?

Tags: java, android, string, date, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM DD HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
try {
      String d1 = list.get(position).getTaskTime(); //here d is "Tue Nov 06 15:37:51 EST 2016"
      date = sdf.parse(d);
      String d2=date.toString();
      Log.d("demo", d2); //here d2 is "Sat Jan 06 15:37:51 EST 2016"
  } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

PS: I used Calendar class to add 10 months and made the date right which is kind of a hack but works. But, I want to know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Please don't link to an image.  Instead, edit your question to show what the values are and how they're incorrect.

Comment: I posted here for the first time. I just used the available option. That link was generated by stackoverflow. Anyways, I updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: It seems that `getTaskTime(` is returning a `String` where you ought to have a method to return a date-time object so you wouldn’t need to parse at all. Be the return type `Date` or `Instant` (I recommend the latter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DD` is wrong. `D` is day of year. Sixth day of year is January 6.

You should use `dd`.

Docs: [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there's an alphabet to specify the day of an year. I assumed D to be the date. I knew it was some silly mistake but didn't know what.