# SimpleDateFormat returning incorrect day on given date

Tags: java, date, datetime-format, simpledateformat, java-time

I was recently doing a question on HackerRank in which I was asked to find the day on a given date. I used `SimpleDateFormat` to find the day.

Below is my code:

```
String sd = Integer.toString(day) + "-" + Integer.toString(month) + "-" + Integer.toString(year);
try {
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-yyyy").parse(sd);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    return sdf.format(d).toUpperCase();
} catch (Exception e) {
    return "";
}
```

The funny thing here is that the above code is printing correct result for today's date i.e. 03/04/2020(`Friday`) but it is returning incorrect day on 05/08/2015(it should return `Wednesday` but instead it returns `Monday`).

Please help me to find the problem.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
I was doing a little mistake that I wanted to use the day of the month, for which `dd` has to be used. `DD` represents the day of the year. That solved my problem!

Comment: What does DD represent?

Comment: Java is case sensitive. According to the _javadoc_ for class `SimpleDateFormat`, **DD** is the day in the year, e.g. 189, whereas **dd** is the day of the month. In any case, perhaps you should consider using the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Comment: It is the date format

Comment: Have you read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Here is an excerpt from that page: _Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer_ Seems to me that simply reading the _javadoc_ for class `SimpleDateFormat` would have helped. Does that explain why your question was down-voted?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I suggest that this answers your question: [Java SimpleDateFormat always returning January for Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560279/java-simpledateformat-always-returning-january-for-month).

Comment: With java.time just use like `LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 3).getDayOfWeek().toString()`. This yields a string of `FRIDAY`. Fill in your variables instead of my hard-coded numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")`.

DD is for day in year, like there are 365 days in a year.

Comment: Do not use [broken Date/Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Your now deleted answer was excellent, perhaps a bit lengthy. Sorry I didn’t have a chance to upvote. Really the best thing we could have done IMHO was to close this question as a duplicate rather then as off-topic, though.

Comment: I certainly know what you mean, @ArvindKumarAvinash. If I have been able to guide, it’s because others have helped me learn here on Stack Overflow. I am afraid that inexplicable downvotes are part of life here too. I get them too. It has taken me a bit to learn just to take them as a curious spice. They don’t really hurt in the big picture.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is using `DD` instead of `dd`.

I also suggest you not to use the outdated date/time API e.g. [java.util.Date and SimpleDateFormat](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Instead, you should use the modern date/time API e.g. types from the packages, [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and [java.time.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) as shown below:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int day = 5;
        int month = 8;
        int year = 2010;
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek();
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US));
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.US));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
THURSDAY
Thursday
Thu
```

**Using `DateTimeFormatter`:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int day = 5;
        int month = 8;
        int year = 2010;
        String sd = String.format("%02d", day) + "-" + String.format("%02d", month) + "-" + String.format("%04d", year);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(sd, formatter);
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek();
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US));
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.US));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
THURSDAY
Thursday
Thu
```