# how to find the power of that number to that digit

Tags: java

Ram is in the process of learning powers of a number.  He is given a number and a digit.  He has to find the power of that number to that digit.

Example if the number is 10 and the digit is  5 the output should be 105 = 100000. If either of the input is negative, the output should be “Invalid Input”.

Help him do this by writing a program in java.  Create a class "Power.java" and write the main method in it. Don't use in-built method to find the power.

Sample Input  1 :
Enter the number
5
Enter the digit
3
Sample Output  1 :
125

Sample Input  2 :
Enter the number
18
Enter the digit
4
Sample Output  2 :
104976

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    long n, p, result = 1;
    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    n = sc.nextLong();
    System.out.println("Enter the digit");
    p = nextLong();

    if (n < 0 || p < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        return;
    }
    if (n >= 0 && p == 0) {
        result = 0;
    } else if (n == 0 && p >= 1) {
        result = 0;
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++) {
            result = result * n;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

During the execution of this program a test case is failed showing
"check logic for power of a number -5"
i don't know what kind of mistake i have made in the program.

Comment: The required test case is failed and shows during the evaluation

Comment: Use Math.pow() function.

Comment: I doubt that this is actually your code `inti=1`. And if it is it probably is part of the problem. If it is not, then please make a [mre].

Comment: A good start would a code that actually compiles.

Comment: You edited as only reaction to my comment. Have you verified that the shown code is now a [mre]?

Comment: No it has no effect in the result

Comment: After fixing all the compilation errors the code returns "Invalid Input" for -5 with "enter..." lines. Perhaps the test case doesn't want the other text you're outputting?

Comment: `n⁰` is `1`, not `0`, i.e. the result when `p == 0` is wrong. --- Except `0⁰` should say `Invalid Input` --- See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_exponent).

Comment: @seven_seas While editing please be more careful and look out for other edits coming in. Your edit (which to my surprise was accepted...) reintroduced a code error which was previously fixed by the asker - and the undone again by another user. (Edit-accepting your proposed edit would have been a good way to handle it....).

Comment: Some one has posted the answer and have deleted it .that is the correct ans re-upload the answer

Comment: @Andreas There is a deleted answer to that effect. Probably deleted because of scared by downvote.... Could be to the point though...

Comment: @AditiSingh Looks like you might get an accept and an upvote if you undelete your answer. But please edit it to add some explanation, then you can also have an upvote by me.

Comment: Unfortunately, Aditi has deleted her answer because of insensible downvoting. Such cases are not rare. Those who have 10k+ points can see what happened with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016495/simpledateformat-returning-incorrect-day-on-given-date/61016911#61016911

Comment: @Andreas 0⁰ is 1 in the view of a [significant fraction of mathematicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero), and Java designers took this direction in the `Math.pow()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        long n, p;
        n = scan.nextLong();
        p = scan.nextLong();
        if(n < 0 || p < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            return;
        }
        if(n == 0 && p == 0) {
            // Math.pow(0, 0) = 1
            System.out.println("1");
            return;
        }
        if (n > 0 && p == 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            return;
        }
        if(n == 0 && p > 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            return;
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("Result:  " + power(n, p));
    }

    private static long power(long n, long p) {
        long result = n;
        for(int i=1; i<p; i++)
            result *= n;
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Actually, mathematically speaking, only `n == 0 && p == 0` is undefined, and the other {any is `0`} cases are perfectly valid.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Actually even this case is fiercely [disputed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero) in the Mathematical community. A fraction of mathematicians define 0^0 to be equal to 1.

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy you are right. I have updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.*;
    public class Power {
         public static void main(String args[]){
             Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
             long n, p;
             System.out.println("Enter the number");
             n = scan.nextLong();
             System.out.println("Enter the digit");
             p = scan.nextLong();
             if(n < 0 || p < 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                return;
             }
             if(n == 0 && p == 0) {
                 System.out.println("Invalid input");
                 return;
             }
             if (n > 0 && p == 0) {
                 System.out.println("1");
                 return;
             }
             if(n == 0 && p > 0) {
                 System.out.println("0");
                 return;
             }
             else 
                 System.out.println(power(n, p));
         }
         private static long power(long n, long p) {
             long result = n;
             for(int i=1; i<p; i++)
                 result *= n;
             return result;
         } 
   }
```

Comment: If it is an answer, please add a short descrition to tell the users that what actually your are doing or how....